# Getting "OperationalError: 1366" from python script - MySQL 5.6 . MySQLdb 1.2.3

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4

Environment:

- MySQL-python-1.2.3.win-amd64-py2.7
- python-2.7.amd64
- mysql-installer-community-5.6.12.2
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter

I am getting Operational Error 1366 when inserting data with a python script. I need to run the [EPFImporter](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/epfimporter.html) which is from 2010

I think the problem is that MySQLdb can only handle `uft8` but not `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. The data I need to import contains utf8mb4 charackters and I may not remove them.

Running the script from CMD comand line gives me following error message after it succesfully inserted ~70.000 rows:

```
2013-07-31 15:14:53,460 [ERROR]: Fatal error encountered while ingesting 'C:\webserver\www\site1\assets\scripts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\webserver\www\site1\assets\scripts\EPFImporter\EPFIngester.py", line 129, in ingestFull
    self._populateTable(self.tmpTableName, skipKeyViolators=skipKeyViolators)
  File "C:\webserver\www\site1\assets\scripts\EPFImporter\EPFIngester.py", line 379, in _populateTable
    cur.execute(exStr)
  File "C:\Windows\python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Windows\python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x8A A...' for column 'description' at row 1")
```

I allready made:

```
ALTER DATABASE databaseXYZ CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

And I changed following from INNODB to:

```
default storage engine  MyISAM  Documentation
default tmp storage engine  MyISAM
```

before this change it was not importing any row at all.

What else can I do? Generally it should be working since on a shared host I was running it on MySQL Server Version: 5.5.28 and it worked fine

**EDIT1**: For testing I installed the latest XAMPP version and under XAMPP the script is running fine with only having the XAMPP-MySQL Server running not the Apache. Python and MySQLdb versions remained the same as before and were untouched. So I am now pretty sure that i did something wrong in the configuration of the MySQL-Server. In XAMPP the DB is running with InnoDB Engine.

Here are the speccs of the XAMPP MYSQL Server:

```
Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.11 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Does anyone has an idea what I could do to trace down the problem in my original MySQL setup? Could it be something in the variable setting, the MYSQL error handling or the Python connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by comparing the XAMPP-MySQL and regular MySQL values in 
phpmyadmin > localhost > variables

I changed a few values in the regular MySQL variables so I am not 100% sure which change finally solved the issue but I guess it was changing to:

```
sql mode    NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

I had a few more other values like strict_mode in there before which i deleted.